# Modular representations of the symplectic group

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, modular-representation-theory, gr.group-theory

Let G=Sp(2m,2) be a finite symplectic group acting on $F_2^{2m}$. This group G acts 2-transitively on $\Omega_{+}$ and on $\Omega_{-}$.  Let $F$ be an algebraic closure of $F_2$.
I am interested to know what are all $G$- invariant sub-spaces of $F^{\Omega_{+}}$ and ${F}
^{\Omega_{-}}$. 
Does anyone know good reference where this is calculated?

Comment: I did a little editing but the question needs more editing as well as an explanation of all the symbols used.   What is the field here?   Is the question about a finite group, an algebraic group, or a Lie group?    There is a lot of literature relevant to actions and representations of symplectic groups over various fields, but the question needs to be stated precisely.

Comment: Here $G$ is a finite syplectic group acting on $F_2^{2m}$.

Comment: As far I understand finite symplectic group acts two transitively only over $F_2$ and it have two sets on which it acts two transitively.